# Spring-Batch second step not working properly

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am configuring a job with two step, Both step need to read different file and dump the data to database. When I am launching the job it executed the first step and save the data successfully and second step is not reading the file. But in database I can see that both Step Status is successful. My Configuration is looks like:

```
job id="job1" job-repository="jobRepository" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" restartable="true">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor">
            <chunk reader="DomainItemReader" writer="DomainItemWriter" commit-interval="40" skip-limit="10">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
                    <exclude class="java.io.FileNotFoundException"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="MyListener"/>
                </listeners>
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
        <next on="COMPLETED" to="step2"/>
    </step>
    <step id="step2" >
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <chunk reader="DomainItemReader2" writer="DomainItemWriter2" commit-interval="100" skip-limit="10">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
                    <exclude class="java.io.FileNotFoundException"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="MyListener2"/>
                </listeners>
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

And my reader is looks like :

```
<bean id="billDomainItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:./firstfile.txt" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter">
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB"/>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.abc.DomainMapper">
                    <property name="accessJobParam" ref="accessJobParam"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And my second step's reader is looks like :

```
<bean id="DomainItemReader2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:./secondFile.txt" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <!-- <property name="names" value="PRODUCT_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRICE" />-->
                    <property name="delimiter">
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB"/>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.abc.DomainMapper2">
                    <property name="accessJobParam" ref="accessJobParam"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can any body please tell me where I am doing wrong and why it is not processing my second step file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed

```
allow-start-if-complete="true"`
```

from my second step and added

```
parent="step1"
```

in my second step and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your second reader configuration

```
<property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.DomainMapper2">
                    <property name="accessJobParam" ref="accessJobParam"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
```

check the bean class mapping `<bean class="com.DomainMapper2">`

does this bean in same package or in different package `<bean class="com.abc.DomainMapper2">`

Comment: Hi Pradeep, Thanks for your response. Both reader are in same package. com.abc.DomainMapper2 and com.abc.DomainMapper1